# How to copy a password protected excel file in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am new in Azure data factory. I know how to copy a unprotected excel file in ADF BUT I want to know if a excel file is password protected then how can I unlock this a copy it to SQL database using ADF.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ADF as of today doesnt support password protected Excel files as a in built functionality.
You would have to write a custom code explicitly to covert the Pwd protected excel into normal excel file which can be done via Azure functions, batch activity etc which in turn can be trigger via ADF .

xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure function code to unlock the excel and extract the data from it. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/274953/unlock-excel-file-when-using-azure-data-factory.html). Azure data factory can call an Azure Function. You can write code to unlock the excel and then another copy activity to copy it to your SQL.